# How to remove "App_data" from a web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications

When I asked VS to create me a web application it also created App_Data. I delete this guy from the local folder structure but he is showing up in the project (in vs). When I try to delete him i get "source controlled item is either exclusively locked elsewhere....)

Comment: If you don't need it; then directly delete it from your project/solution and that gets synced up with your local folder as well.

Comment: when i go to tfs source control i dont see the app_data folder. when I go to local file system i dont see the app_data folder. but it shows up solution (project) file structure in vs.

Answer (score 9):

To delete the App_Data folder, first delete it from your local file system. Close your solution in Visual Studio if you have it open. Then, in Source Control Explorer, manually check out your .csproj file (or .vbproj, etc). Open the project file in a text editor and search for this:

```
<Folder Include="App_Data\" />
```

Delete that line and save & close the file. In Source Control Explorer, check the file back in. When you reopen your project in Visual Studio, the App_Data folder should be gone.

Comment: good one.Any idea why it is not deleting via normally.Is it a bug?